# How to add fragments to the back stack programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment-backstack

I have 4 fragments FragmentA, FragmentB,  FragmentC and  FragmentX. Once I move from FragmentX to Fragment C I want the  FragmentA  FragmentB added to back stack as if passed onto A,then B before. If I push back the order should be  B, A.

```java
Snackbar.make(view, "Nueva linea de seguimiento guardada", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction("Action", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") // Id like to avoid this !!!
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      //navController.getBackStack() ... ????? add the fragmets
      navController.navigate(R.id.action_FragmentX_to_detalleFragmentC); 
    }
  }).show();
```

```java
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: I suggest using Deeplinks with Flag -> https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link